# Swift - Core Data error when adding attribute (easy)

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

When I add a new attribute "tempt" in my ".xcdatamodel" file and add the a new NSManagedObject in my model-file like this:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Model)
class Model: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var username: String
    @NSManaged var tempt: String

}
```

I get an error when running my app. Must I "activate" my attributes in some way to not get this error? I just don't understand what it could be since I'm not using this new attribute anywhere in my app.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you add it to the model itself ?

Comment: *"I get an error when running my app"* – What error? At what line exactly in your source code?  Do you know that changing the model requires you to either remove the old store file or perform some kind of migration (perhaps automatic lightweight migration)? There is a "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" by Apple.

Comment: @shannoga If you mean adding it to the ".xcdatamodel" file, then yes.

Comment: @MartinR NSLocalizedFailureReason: There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.] No I did not know that changing the model requires to remove the old file; what does this mean, exactly? And what does it mean to perform a migration?